# How to sum up the specific part of elements?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, arraylist

I am very stuck in this. Please help.

Sample data

```
Year  Rate
2002  1.0
2002  1.0
2002  1.1
2003  1.5
2003  5.4
2003  6.5
2004  9.5 
2004  12.5
2004  11.3
```

How do I sum up the elements by year using Java programming language?
Ex. Add up all the rates from the year of 2002. Then, add up all the rates from the year of 2003...

Should I split the array into specific parts first or else?

I have no idea. Please help(**not an answer but suggestions**).

Comment: Sorry, we are not going to do your homework for you. If you have a specific technical problem we are happy to help.

Comment: @BhavikShah how's that supposed to help someone who's in learning phase?

Comment: what have you tried so far? do you have the input already available in java? is the data read from file, into some array? could you post some code of your ideas so far? how should the output look?

Comment: Is this Data present in any map? Or these are two different arrays?

Answer (score 2):

Split the data ([String.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)) then iterate over it two at a time, putting the results into a [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put%28K,%20V%29).

```
// Do the split, initialize a Map.
for( int i=0; i < splitResult.length; i+=2) {
    // Use your map
}
```

Comment: The question was for a starter in the language. But don't worry, OP has cancelled the SO account.

Answer (score 1):

A (tree) map could be a nice datastructure for your task:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> ratesPerYear = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
for (/* each pair of values */) {
   Integer previousResult = ratesPerYear.get(/* year */);
   if (previousResult == null) {
      previousResult = 0;
   }
   ratesPerYear.put(/* year */, previousResult + /* rate */);
}

System.out.println("Total rates for 2003: " + ratesPerYear.get(2003));
```

The code is not valid java, you'll have some comments to replace ;)